# adding div dynamically using only javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here is the part of my code.

I want to create a div element dynamically using JavaScript only; I am doing it for the first time using code from different websites and questions from here only.

But this loop seems to be doing nothing.

All the classes do exist in the CSS. Please, find the error and any other suggestions are most welcome.

```js
var i;

for (i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
  var main = document.getElementById('show');

  var div1 = document.createElement('div');
  div1.id = 's' + i;
  div1.className = 'perschoolcontainer';
  var link2 = document.createElement('a');
  link2.setAttribute('href', 'abcd.jpg');

  var image3 = document.createElement('img');
  image3.id = 'dp';
  image3.src = 'davsv.jpg';
  image3.class = 'dp';

  var p4 = document.createElement('p');
  p4.id = 'sname';
  p4.class = 'sname';

  var p5 = document.createElement('p');
  p5.id = 'location';
  p5.class = 'location';

  var t1 = document.createTextNode('abc');
  var t2 = document.createTextNode('def');

  p5.appendChild(t2);
  p4.appendChild(t1);
  link2.appendChild(image3);
  link2.appendChild(p4);
  link2.appendChild(p5);
  div1.appendChild(link2);

  main.innerHTML.appendChild(div1);
}
```

```html
<div id="s1" class="perschoolcontainer">
  <a href="davsv.jpg">
    <img id="dp" class="dp" src="davsv.jpg" alt="DAV">
    <div id="details" class="details">
      <p id="sname" class="sname">DAV</p>
      <p id="location" class="location">Sv</p>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: You want us to scroll to the riiiiiiiiiiiiight?

Comment: appendChild instead of innerHtml.appendChild in last row

Comment: For the next time: open the browsers console and check it for errors ( quite helpful)

Comment: var main = document.getElementById('show'); --> you don't have an element with this id

Comment: @Jonasw yeahh it's working..thnx

Comment: @Sudhanshu Saini : please mark trincots answer as the answer because he was 3secs faster... :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`innerHTML` does not have a `appendChild` method. Change:

```
main.innerHTML.appendChild(div1);
```

to:

```
main.appendChild(div1);
```